# Unable to export Enterprise Build in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios

I am unable to export enterprise build in Xcode 7. I have correct Distribution profile and I have taken enterprise build in Xcode 5.1. But after upgrading to Xcode 7.1 I am unable to take build. Please Help me.

This is what Xcode 7.1 shows

"to save for enterprise deployment you need to add an apple id account that is enrolled"

Comment: Did you add your enterprise account under Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts ?

Comment: Ofcourse I added the same In which I have taken Enterprise build in Xcode 5.1.